# How to parse one or more complex object list in one response by ksoap2

Tags: android, wsdl, ksoap2

server gives me a complex xml response. it's has three complex object list.but unlike other complex object list, it did't standard defined.
Here's the wsdl defination:

```
<xs:complexType name="SinseiDataForMobile">
  <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="originalHeader" type="HeaderData" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" /> 
  <xs:element name="dispHeader" type="HeaderDataForMobile" maxOccurs="unbounded" /> 
  <xs:element name="dispBody" type="BodyDataForMobile" maxOccurs="unbounded" /> 
  <xs:element name="dispHyo" type="HelloDataForMobile" maxOccurs="unbounded" /> 
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

and the response xml:

```
<ns2:sinseiData>
        <ns2:originalHeader>
           <ns2:syoruiCode>test002</ns2:syoruiCode>
           <ns2:syoruiName>test002</ns2:syoruiName>
           <ns2:syoruiHan>1</ns2:syoruiHan>
        </ns2:originalHeader>
        <ns2:dispHeader>
           <ns2:key>SHD_HKD</ns2:key>
           <ns2:value>2012</ns2:value>
        </ns2:dispHeader>
        <ns2:dispHeader>
           <ns2:key>SHD_KBN_KINKYU</ns2:key>
           <ns2:value>ss</ns2:value>
        </ns2:dispHeader>
        <ns2:dispHeader>
           <ns2:key>SHD_SRI_CODE</ns2:key>
           <ns2:value>test002</ns2:value>
        </ns2:dispHeader>
        <ns2:dispHeader>
           <ns2:key>SHD_SRI_NAME</ns2:key>
           <ns2:value>test002</ns2:value>
        </ns2:dispHeader>
        <ns2:dispHeader>
           <ns2:key>SHD_HKU_NO</ns2:key>
           <ns2:value>a002</ns2:value>
        </ns2:dispHeader>
        <ns2:dispHeader>
           <ns2:key>SHD_HKU_NAME</ns2:key>
           <ns2:value>asdf　ad</ns2:value>
        </ns2:dispHeader>
        <ns2:dispHeader>
           <ns2:key>SHD_HKU_SID</ns2:key>
           <ns2:value>test001</ns2:value>
        </ns2:dispHeader>
        <ns2:dispHeader>
           <ns2:key>SHD_HKU_SNAME</ns2:key>
           <ns2:value>test001</ns2:value>
        </ns2:dispHeader>
        <ns2:dispHeader>
           <ns2:key>SHD_ATN</ns2:key>
           <ns2:value/>
        </ns2:dispHeader>
        <ns2:dispBody>
           <ns2:koumokuSyubetu>1</ns2:koumokuSyubetu>
           <ns2:value>0022</ns2:value>
        </ns2:dispBody>
        <ns2:dispHyo>
           <ns2:hyoNo>1</ns2:hyoNo>
           <ns2:hyoName>table1</ns2:hyoName>
        </ns2:dispHyo>
        <ns2:dispHyo>
           <ns2:hyoNo>2</ns2:hyoNo>
           <ns2:hyoName>table2</ns2:hyoName>
        </ns2:dispHyo>
     </ns2:sinseiData>
```

How can i handle this three uncertain length list. soapEnvelope mapping doesn't works in here.
Any help will be appreciate!

Answer (score -1):

See this blog about ksoap [Getting Started with KSOAP on Android](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/)

Hope It will help.

Comment: Too see http://roderickbarnes.com/blog/droid-chronicles-web-services-handling-complex-parameters

Comment: i'v see this blog, the example just parse only one list, so she can tree property from 1 to list's length.But my question is how to parse three uncertain length list